# Using both memcached and taskqueue on the google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, task-queue

[image: taskqueue and memcache]

I am trying to achieve the above on the google apps engine, and was wondering if anyone knows of a project that this has already been done? or an example?

So far in my implementation I can write a single object to memory. However, I am having issues in using add_multi to input multiple objects.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: it looks straightforward to implement, what is not clear in particular?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're describing a write-behind cache. You should bear in mind that data can be evicted from memcache at any time, so there could easily be a window in which submitted data is not available, as it's been evicted from memcache and not yet written to the datastore. You should also be aware that there's a limit on taskqueue payloads of 10k. Given the relatively low overhead of writing a single entity to the datastore, this is probably far simpler and more reliable than implementing a write-behind cache.

If you're having specific trouble implementing this, you need to give us more details as to what problems you have before we can help.

Comment: doesn't his diagram show writing to the cache *before* adding to datastore? this looks like a common architecture on App Engine to get around the fact that datastore access is *slow* i.e. load everything from memcache where possible.

Comment: @Anentropic It pretty clearly shows adding the object in memory, then adding a task to write it to the datastore. That's write-behind.